# Multiple GET under a single resource: REST API

Tags: java, rest, jax-ws

I'm trying to create two GET requests which are linked with each other, that is, one is a child of the other. Please have a look at the below code:

```
@GET
@QueryParam("{customerId}")
  public List<customerModel> getCustomers(@QueryParam("customerId") Long customerId) {
if (customerId== null || customerId== 0)
  throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("400: customerId cannot be null!").build());
try {
   ......
   ......
  return findCustomer(customerId); 
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Exception occurred when fetching the master detail customerId:" + customerId+", error :"+e.getMessage(), e);
  throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("......").build());
}
  }

@GET
@Path("{customerId}/moreInfo")
  public List<customerInfoModel> getCustomerInfo(@PathParam("customerId") Long customerId) {
    if (customerId== null || customerId== 0)
      throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("customerId cannot be null").build());
try {
  .....
  .....
  return getCustomerInfo(customerId);
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Exception occurred when fetching the customer detail customerId:" + e.getMessage(), e);
  throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("....").build());
}
  }
```

If we notice, both of the GET calls are doing the same initial and logging work. The only difference is the method calls. Is there a way to write the same code only calling different function depending on the path?

Comment: Why don't you create another pathparam /{moreinfo} and just check if this param is present or not ?

Comment: What's the framework that you use for this?

Comment: @CamilleGerin-Roze, can we do that? Can you provide a one line example of how can we do this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your methods are the exact same other than `findCustomer(customerId);` and `getCustomerInfo(customerId);`, but both methods return a `List<customerModel>`, so that is confusing.

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry that was a typo, they def return different models

Comment: In Spring you can define multiple path for a controller, so you can try to put a path with the argument, and a path without it in the annotation

Answer (score 0):

You could extract some methods. One for ID checking. One for logging errors.

```
public interface IdChecker {
    public void checkId(Long id);
}
```

```
public class CustomerWebService extends ... implements IdChecker {

    @Override
    public void checkId(Long id) {
        if (id == null || id == 0)
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("400: customerId cannot be null!").build());
    }

    private void logMessage(Exception e, String reason) {
        log.error(String.format("Exception occurred when %s", reason), e);
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("......").build());
    }

    @GET
    @QueryParam("{customerId}")
    public List<customerModel> getCustomers(@QueryParam("customerId") Long customerId) {
        checkId(customerId);
        try {
           ......
           ......
          return findCustomer(customerId); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String action = "fetching the master detail customerId:" + customerId;
            logMessage(e, action);
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{customerId}/moreInfo")
    public List<customerInfoModel> getCustomerInfo(@PathParam("customerId") Long customerId) {
        checkId(customerId);
        try {
          .....
          .....
          return getCustomerInfo(customerId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String action = "fetching the customer detail customerId:" + customerId;
            logMessage(e, action);
        }
    }
```